# JavaScript Associative array with "themes"

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

First of all, sorry for my English, hopefully I can explain my problem to you well enough.

I want to create a theme-based quiz and I need help building the arrays with themes, questions and answers. So far I got this :

```
var aarhus={
       question: 'Is this a aarhus question?',
       answer1:'yes',
       answer2:'no',
       answer3:'I dunno',
       answer4:'stfu',
       correctAnswer:'stfu'
       };

var multimedia={
       question: 'Is this a multimedia question?',
       answer1:'yes',
       answer2:'no',
       answer3:'I dunno',
       answer4:'stfu',
       correctAnswer:'stfu'
       };

var general={
       question: 'Is this a general question?',
       answer1:'yes',
       answer2:'no',
       answer3:'I dunno',
       answer4:'stfu',
       correctAnswer:'stfu'
       };
```

There I have 3 arrays that represent themes. They store the question, 4 possible answers and the correct answer. The problem is I only have one question in each theme. And so my question is - how can I add more questions to themes ? I need to able to access any any question with it's answers within themes (let's say 2 questions with their own answers for each theme).

Thank you!

Comment: I would recommend *not* calling JavaScript objects "associative arrays" or "arrays". I realize PHP and a couple of other languages use the term, but as JavaScript uses the word "array" to mean something else, using "array" to mean "object" leads to confusion. The usual term you hear (other than "object" of course) is "map".

Comment: sorry, my bad. I forgot to add that I would like to put those objects into an array afterwards. Sorry again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to nitpick, those are "plain" objects and not arrays.  You can use nested objects and arrays to group questions, though:

```
var questions =
{
    theme1:
    [
        {
            question: "this is question 1",
            answers: ["one", "two", "three"],
            correct: "two"
        },
        {
            question: "this is question 2",
            answers: ["one", "two", "three"],
            correct: "three"
        }
    ],
    theme2:
    [
        {
            question: "this is question 1",
            answers: ["one", "two", "three"],
            correct: "two"
        },
        {
            question: "this is question 2",
            answers: ["one", "two", "three"],
            correct: "three"
        }
    ]
}

//To access the second question of theme 2
questions.theme2[1].question
```

Comment: Yup, this seems to be what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just make the themes an array:

```
var general=[{
   question: 'Is this a general question?',
   answer1:'yes',
   answer2:'no',
   answer3:'I dunno',
   answer4:'stfu',
   correctAnswer:'stfu'
   }];
```

Then you can add a new question to the theme using `array.push`:

```
general.push({
   question: 'Is this a second general question?',
   answer1:'yes',
   answer2:'no',
   answer3:'I dunno',
   answer4:'stfu',
   correctAnswer:'stfu'
});
```

Access them like you would any array:

```
var questionIndex = 1; // question #2 in the theme
console.log(general[questionIndex].question); // "Is this a second general question?"
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this solution will help:

```
<html><head><title>Test</title></head>
<script>
var MULTIMEDIA = 'Multimedia';

var question1 = {
   question: 'Is this a multimedia question1?',
   answer1:'yes',
   answer2:'no',
   answer3:'I dunno',
   answer4:'stfu',
   correctAnswer:'stfu'
   };
var question2 = {
   question: 'Is this a multimedia question2?',
   answer1:'yes',
   answer2:'no',
   answer3:'I dunno',
   answer4:'stfu',
   correctAnswer:'stfu'
   };
var question3 = {
   question: 'Is this a multimedia question3?',
   answer1:'yes',
   answer2:'no',
   answer3:'I dunno',
   answer4:'stfu',
   correctAnswer:'stfu'
   };

var questions = [];    
questions[0] = question1;
questions[1] = question2;
questions[2] = question3;

var theme = {
questions : questions
}
var themes = [];
themes[MULTIMEDIA] = theme;
</script>
<body>
<label>

<script>
var questionNo = 0;
document.write(themes[MULTIMEDIA].questions[questionNo].question + '<br>');
document.write('<ul>');
document.write('<li>' + themes[MULTIMEDIA].questions[questionNo].answer1 + '</li>');
document.write('<li>' + themes[MULTIMEDIA].questions[questionNo].answer2 + '</li>');
document.write('<li>' + themes[MULTIMEDIA].questions[questionNo].answer3 + '</li>');
document.write('</ul>');

</script>

</label>
</body>
</html>
```